# Why is translate3d leaking DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, memory-leaks

Consider this HTML page:

http://jsbin.com/aYUcelo/1/
(i recommend downloading it to get rid of all the jsbin noise).

With a click on the GO button a div is added to the body. RM removes one of the divs.
Also it applies one of two styles to the new div:

```
newDiv.style.color = "red";
// or
newDiv.style.WebkitTransform = "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)";
```

You can see a constantly growing number of nodes in the chrome dev tools memory timeline,  the GC can not remove, if the WebkitTransform is applied. This does not happen with the color red style.

edit: just to make clear that applying the "red style" the operation of adding and removing the divs is node count equivalent.

**What is the reason for this behaviour? Am i missing the point? Is there even no DOM node leak?**

Here you can find two timeline records:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9S6doraVaWXdjRyWjluMW1BUlU (translate)
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9S6doraVaWXQVAwbFpfZzh1RVE (red)

In both records 3 divs are added and removed in a row and a GC is requested finally.
Just for your info: i have a more complex angular app, but i can hunt down the memory leak to the same issue. Anyway I created this easier example.

Edit: two images of the timeline records:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9S6doraVaWXMURzMjdhMWI0UDA
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9S6doraVaWXWGhwVWhlMjN4dkE

Edit 2: running Windows 8 / Chrome 30.0.1599.69 m

Comment: There is a chromium bug filed, that describes the same issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304689

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio 2013 by chance? if so, check your network panel and see if there is a correlation between any XHR activity, and the erratic object manipulation in memory.  If this is the case, this is due to the fact that Visual Studio 2013 comes integrated with a signalR browser monitor which runs while testing your project in the browser you deploy it with.